# Can I edit View/Materialized View script in Toad?

Tags: oracle, toad

Can I edit View/Materialized View script in Toad? Because it waste time to drop and rebuilt a view/Materialized view if I want to update its script? Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are differentiating between a view and a materialized view here. With a view it is simply a text string of the sql which creates the view which is stored behind the scenes so there is no overhead here except to parse the sql and check whether any related objects are affected. With a materialized view it may invalidate the current data you have cached but this will be refreshed when the view is next run (read documentation on materialized views to explain this process)

Answer (score 0):

See it in schema browser, then double click on it to open in the editor.

To compile it again (it's the only method to edit it) press F9.

It will completely overwrite the old SP.

Answer (score 0):

To edit a view inside toad:

1. Right click on the 'View' in toad.
2. Select 'Alter View'.
3. Make your changes and click on 'ok'
4. Right click on the 'view' again.
5. Click on 'Compile View'